# Debugging an OAuth client bad response. I'm using PHP, Laravel5.3, PHPLeague OAuth Client and Guzzle

Tags: php, oauth, guzzle, oauth2client, clio-api

Let me start by thank you for taking the time. I'm a newbie so let me know if you need more information.

So I'm trying to setup an OAUTH2 client in Laravel to connect up to an API  provided by [CLIO](http://api-docs.clio.com/v2/). I'm using [PHPLeague's OAuth2 Client Library](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) which uses [GUZZLE](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) to handle HTTP.

I was able to setup the client to redirect to Clio's Authorization page, authorize the access, get redirected to my app and receive an authorization code.

In the next step where I need to send a request to get an Access Token something goes wrong!

Here is the error I receive:

Type error: Argument 1 passed to League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider::prepareAccessTokenResponse() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Users/patrick/Sites/ssacorp/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php on line [565](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/master/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php#L700)

---

Now, in order to track it down, I know the following method is called to start fetching the access token:

```
public function getAccessToken($grant, array $options = [])
{
    $grant = $this->verifyGrant($grant);
    $params = [
        'client_id'     => $this->clientId,
        'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
        'redirect_uri'  => $this->redirectUri,
    ];
    $params   = $grant->prepareRequestParameters($params, $options);
    $request  = $this->getAccessTokenRequest($params);
    $response = $this->getParsedResponse($request);
    $prepared = $this->prepareAccessTokenResponse($response);
    $token    = $this->createAccessToken($prepared, $grant);
    return $token;
}
```

I dumped the properties and I get:

**$params**

```
array(5) { ["client_id"]=> string(40) "*************************************" ["client_secret"]=> string(40) "************************************" ["redirect_uri"]=> string(26) "http://app.ssadv.org/oauth" ["grant_type"]=> string(18) "authorization_code" ["code"]=> string(20) "******************" }
```

So everything seems normal here. I'm not sharing these credentials of course.

**$request**

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)#179 (7) { ["method":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> string(4) "POST" ["requestTarget":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> NULL ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri)#181 (7) { ["scheme":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(4) "http" ["userInfo":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["host":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(12) "app.clio.com" ["port":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> NULL ["path":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(12) "/oauth/token" ["query":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["fragment":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" } ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> array(2) { ["Host"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "app.clio.com" } ["content-type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } } ["headerNames":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> array(2) { ["content-type"]=> string(12) "content-type" ["host"]=> string(4) "Host" } ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> string(3) "1.1" ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#183 (7) { ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> resource(262) of type (stream) ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> NULL ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> string(10) "php://temp" ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> array(0) { } } } inside Transfer
```

**$response**

This is actually the string going into the method prepareAccessTokenResponse() which is supposed to be an array and is causing the main error. Dumping it reveals that its actually a 404 HTML page by CLIO:

```html
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"\n
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n
\n
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">\n
\n
<head>\n
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />\n
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>\n
</head>\n
\n
<body>\n
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->\n
\n
  <div class="dialog">\n
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>\n
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>\n
  </div>\n
</body>\n
\n
</html>
```

---

I have tested the link and parameters in Postman and confirmed the access token is in fact returned using the same URI and information in my $params. Why am I getting a 404 when my URI is correct and $request says it is using POST method as it has to. To confirm this though, I tried using Chrome's Dev Tools Network tool but was unable to find a POST call to that link. How else should I troubleshoot this to make sure Guzzle is sending the right data to the right address?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was that I have to use https vs http for the POST request to go through. Token granted. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Curl
I had to `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`